# MySQL split column values for use in sub-query?

Tags: mysql

I am using a plugin for OpenCart that is combining a number of ids into a single string and storing them in a single column. Example values are `21760` and `6772:15499:15497`. The number of concatenated ids can range from 1 to 5 (most are two or three ids).

I am looking to get the name values of these ids in a query result, concatenated in the same order as the ids are stored in.

For simplicities sake assume the two tables only have two columns (in reality there is a third table that I want to do a join on, but that is irrelevant to the immediate issue):

Table `a`:

```
|id    | name        |
|6773  | Google      |
|15497 | Apple       |
|15500 | Microsoft   |
|...   | ...         |
```

and

Table `b`:

```
|id    | var                 |
|123   | 6773:15500:15497    |
|543   | 45688               |
|22311 | 885:2588            |
|...   | ...                 |
```

Based on a `var` of `6773:15500:15497` I want the output of the query to be `Google:Microsoft:Apple`

I have no idea of where to begin with this sort of query.

Comment: I think this is not very good way of storing information you need to work with. Much better solution would be to create many to many relationship between a and b table!

Comment: I agree. I said that to my co-developer. However, I am working with a third-party plugin that has done it this way and recreating it is not an option (it would take too long)

Comment: Hi look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6b7b/26) solution... I play a little with this problem... The problem with this solution is that you have to know max number of var in one cell and write if statement for that number of time...

Comment: So if you know that it's 5 max than you need to add one more if statement and one more left join and it will work like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to keep data this way.

The first idea come into my head is : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dd77/4

```
SELECT b.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR ':')
FROM table2 as b
LEFT JOIN table1 as a
on b.var = a.id 
  OR  b.var regexp(CONCAT('^',a.id,':'))
  OR  b.var regexp(CONCAT(':',a.id,':'))
  OR  b.var regexp(CONCAT(':',a.id,'$'))
 GROUP BY b.id
```

**EDIT 1**

Ordered variant: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dd77/38

```
SELECT b.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(a.id, REPLACE(b.var,":",",")) SEPARATOR ':' )
FROM table2 as b
LEFT JOIN table1 as a
on b.var = a.id 
  OR  b.var regexp(CONCAT('^',a.id,':'))
  OR  b.var regexp(CONCAT(':',a.id,':'))
  OR  b.var regexp(CONCAT(':',a.id,'$'))
 GROUP BY b.id
```

Comment: Looking at the code, this would not work for vars with more or less then 3 ids?

Comment: I love its relative simplicity. Can it be made to show the `a.name` in the same order as they are stored in `b.var`?

Comment: Thank you. But as I said at the first line of my answer, it is not a good question, and my query is not really good from many points of view. Especially for big tables. While you have a small one it could work, but for real high load database I am sure we will need to refactor everything :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do a Procedure. 
First check out how many strings you have separate by a delimiter.
Then, split their values based on their position. 
Then, store the values into a variables. 
Finally, do the select that you want and return it.

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE SPLIT_STR_AND_RETURN(str VARCHAR(255) IN, delimiter VARCHAR(12) IN)
    BEGIN
    -- DEFINE MY VARIABLES
    DEFINE v_count_str INT;
    DEFINE v_index INT DEFAULT 1;
    DEFINE v_id_target CHAR(60);
    DEFINE v_name TEXT;

    -- CREATE A TABLE WHERE I STORE THE VALUES
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS stored_values_tmp; -- make sure it doesnt already exist
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stored_values_tmp (
      name_str varchar(120)
    ) ENGINE=memory;

    -- GET HOW MANY IDs I HAVE
    SELECT (LENGTH( str ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( str, delimiter,  '' ) ))+1 INTO v_count_str;
    -- DO A LOOP FOR OBTAINT THE IDs. POSITION = index
    WHILE v_index <= v_count_str DO
      -- SPLIT THE STRING
      SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delimiter, v_index),
           LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delimiter, v_index -1)) + 1),
           delimiter, '') INTO v_id_target;
      -- GET THE NAME
      SELECT name INTO v_name FROM table_a WHERE id = v_id_target
      -- STORE
      INSERT INTO stored_values_tmp(name_str) VALUES(v_name);
    END WHILE;

    -- GET THE RESULT
    SELECT * FROM stored_values_tmp;

    -- DROP TMP TABLE
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE stored_values_tmp;
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Finally, call the procedure:

```
CALL SPLIT_STR_AND_RETURN('6772:15499:15497',':');
```

Comment: I created a very similar one and run a single query wich uses the

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution and it will work but only if you know for sure that the max number of concatenated ids is 5... If there is six somewhere then you need to extend the query:

```
SELECT tx.id, CONCAT_WS(':', t1.name, t2.name, t3.name, t4.name, t5.name) as var
FROM (SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 1) as sub,          
           IF((LENGTH(var) - LENGTH(REPLACE (var, ':', ''))) > 0,  
           TRIM(LEADING CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 1)), ':') FROM (SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 2))), '') as sub2,
           IF((LENGTH(var) - LENGTH(REPLACE (var, ':', ''))) > 1,  
           TRIM(LEADING CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 2)), ':') FROM (SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 3))), '') as sub3,
           IF((LENGTH(var) - LENGTH(REPLACE (var, ':', ''))) > 2,  
           TRIM(LEADING CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 3)), ':') FROM (SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 4))), '') as sub4,
           IF((LENGTH(var) - LENGTH(REPLACE (var, ':', ''))) > 3,  
           TRIM(LEADING CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 4)), ':') FROM (SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 5))), '') as sub5
       FROM table2) as tx
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON tx.sub = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
ON tx.sub2 = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table1 t3
ON tx.sub3 = t3.id
LEFT JOIN table1 t4
ON tx.sub4 = t4.id
LEFT JOIN table1 t5
ON tx.sub5 = t5.id
```

Here is SQL Fiddle for that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a2f50/1

This solution is not most elegant but it will do the job.

Also this

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 1) as sub,          
           IF((LENGTH(var) - LENGTH(REPLACE (var, ':', ''))) > 0,  
           TRIM(LEADING CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 1)), ':') FROM (SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 2))), '') as sub2,
           IF((LENGTH(var) - LENGTH(REPLACE (var, ':', ''))) > 1,  
           TRIM(LEADING CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 2)), ':') FROM (SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 3))), '') as sub3,
           IF((LENGTH(var) - LENGTH(REPLACE (var, ':', ''))) > 2,  
           TRIM(LEADING CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 3)), ':') FROM (SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 4))), '') as sub4,
           IF((LENGTH(var) - LENGTH(REPLACE (var, ':', ''))) > 3,  
           TRIM(LEADING CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 4)), ':') FROM (SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ':', 5))), '') as sub5
       FROM table2
```

part of code will return you the table like this

```
 +----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 | id |sub1     |sub2     |sub3     |sub4     |sub5     |  
 +----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 |123 |6773     |15500    |15479    |         |         |
 +----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 |543 |15497    |1        |         |         |         |
 +----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
  ...
```

here is Faddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a2f50/2

So you can use it somehow to preform other operation on base table like update, search or something like that...

GL!