# Column having multiple value with comma

Tags: mysql, sql

there are 3 tables like below

Table: prod p

```
+-----+--------------+
|codes|desc          |
+-----+--------------+
|100  |table 1       |
|101  |chair 1       |
|102  |chair 2       |
+-----+--------------+
```

Table: prod_details d

```
+-----+--------------+
|codes|mat_id        |
+-----+--------------+
|100  |50,52         |
|101  |53            |
|102  |51,52,54      |
+-----+--------------+
```

Table: materials

```
+------+-------------+
|mat_id|mat_name     |
+------+-------------+
|50    |pine wood    |
|51    |acacia wood  |
|52    |MDF          |
|53    |stainless s  |
|54    |leather      | 
+------+-------------+
```

I want a result like this:

```
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
|code |mat_id     |mat_name                |
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
|100  |50,52      |pine wood,MDF           |
|101  |53         |stainless s             |
|102  |51,52,54   |acacia wood,MDF,leather |
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
```

however material name shows one only, like this:

```
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
|code |mat_id     |mat_name                |
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
|100  |50,52      |pine wood               |
|101  |53         |stainless s             |
|102  |51,52,54   |acacia wood             |
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
```

I'm using the below query but apparently doesn't work.

```
SELECT p.codes, d.mat_id, 
(SELECT group_concat(mat_name separator',') FROM materials WHERE mat_id IN (d.mat_id))
FROM prod p
LEFT JOIN prod_details d on (p.codes=d.codes)
GROUP BY p.codes
```

I understand the table is designed badly however I can't change it. 
Also I'm not able to use php with the circumstance so need to be sorted by mysql only.

It would be appreciative if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565318/mysql-split-column-values-for-use-in-sub-query/29603475#29603475) it's look similar to me :) GL

Comment: Don't store data like you do, with comma separated items in a column. It will only cause you lots of problems...

Comment: Thank you for advice everyone. I don't store multiple values in one column anymore but the table was created 4-5 years ago and having too many data so I can't change it now. But yes, I will definitely all your advise from now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to know that you have a very poor design.  You should put effort in to fix it, and remember two things:  (1) Never store lists in delimited strings.  (2) Don't store numeric id's in character fields.

That said, you can get what you want with the rather painful query:

```
select pd.*,
       group_concat(m.mat_name) as mat_names
from prod_details pd left join
     materials m
     on find_in_set(m.mat_id, p.mat_id) > 0
group by pd.codes;
```

Note:  there is no guarantee that the names will be in the same order as the `ids`.  If you want to guarantee that, reconstruct the ids:

```
select pd.codes, group_concat(m.mat_id order by m.mat_id) as mat_ids,
       group_concat(m.mat_name order by m.mat_id) as mat_names
from prod_details pd left join
     materials m
     on find_in_set(m.mat_id, p.mat_id) > 0
group by pd.codes;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I've tried and it's sorted now. Thank you very much for your prompt help and yes, I'll always remember your advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select distinct t.codes,t.id1,
STUFF((SELECT ',' + mtr.mat_name FROM material  mtr WHERE  t.id1  like '%'+CONVERT(varchar(10),mtr.mat_id)+'%'
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
 from 
(select pd.codes,pd.mat_id as id1,m.mat_id as id2,m.mat_name from prod_details pd inner join material m on  pd.mat_id like '%'+CONVERT(varchar(10),m.mat_id)+'%')
as t
```